# Trying to profile php script but destructors are vague

Tags: php, trace, profiling

I'm got the following php trace and as u can see there's a huge delay in the constructors for one of the classes but i'm unable to determine why because it doesn't tell me which type of child class extends it.  How do i get more information on the trace to determine this information.

The code for the __destruct() is simple.

```
  public function __destruct(){
    unset($this->dbObject);
  }




   0.2180    8723832           -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
    0.2180    8720752           -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
    0.2184    8067856           -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
   84.2555    8081936         -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
   84.2556    8065984         -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
   84.2557    8052888         -> SIT_Authority->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_Authority.php:0
   84.2557    8052960         -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
   84.2557    8048936         -> SIT_DB_Base->__destruct() /usr/local/share/sit/sitlib-2.18/SIT_DB_Base.php:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$classReflection = new ReflectionClass($classObject);
echo $classReflection->getName();
```

You can also check below for more information about the reflection object :

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)